# How parallel stream uses the ForkJoinPool

Tags: java

I am little bit confused about common ForkJoiPool in parallel streaming. As some people said that parallel streaming uses the common ForkJoiPool to execute the tasks and if any of the task get stucked or taking long time, it will impact the others tasks. So here If a task get stucked in parallel streaming while on list1, will it impact the parallel streaming on list2? Or there will not be any impact on list2 parallel streaming.

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    list1.add("abc");
    list1.add("def");
    list1.add("ghi");
    list1.add("jkl");
    list1.add("xyz");

    // Returning =  [xyz]
    System.out.println(list1.parallelStream().filter(s -> s.equals("xyz")).collect(Collectors.toList()));

    List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    list2.add(111);
    list2.add(222);
    list2.add(333);
    list2.add(444);

    // Returning =  [444]
    System.out.println(list2.parallelStream().filter(s -> s > 333).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: The parallelism is only happening inside the `Stream`. So your first stream is always finished before the second can begin

Comment: What @Lino said. Moreover, if you had two different threads doing the two parallel streams instead of one serially (as appears to be now), the problem might appear due to `thread starvation` and then *all processes/threads* trying to acquire threads to use into their parallel streams or otherwise would block waiting for threads to be free.

Comment: @Lino, I mean to say that both are running in parallel....

Comment: Then you're hideing some code. Can you provide an example which does show what you're trying to do?